# Computed Column Specification

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2014

```
CREATE TABLE PaperTable
(
    PaperID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
 , PageNumber varchar(100)
  , PaperAlphaID AS Cast(Right(Year(getDate()),2) as varchar(2)) +'-'+ PageNumber
);
```

Result I got when I added "001" and "002" in as my paper number:

```
PaperID   PageNumber  PaperAlphaID
-------   ----------  ------------
  1         001          15-001
  2         002          15-002
```

But I want to display whole year in PaperAlphaID

```
PaperID   PageNumber  PaperAlphaID
-------   ----------  ------------
  1         001          2015-001
  2         002          2015-002
```

Instead of 15-001 and 15-002

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove RIGHT function and Update `varchar(4)`

```
CREATE TABLE PaperTable
(
   PaperID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
   , PageNumber varchar(100)
   ,   PaperAlphaID AS Cast(Year(getDate())) as varchar(4)) +'-'+ PageNumber
);
```